# Defaulting to last part of else if statement in java

Tags: java

I am writhing a code to find the distance between 2 places where the user inputs different cities. i need to get the longitude and latitude of the two places, so i tried writing the code like this, but for some reason that i do not know, it always uses the coordinantes for orlando no matter what. Could anyone please help me?

(The latitudeStringOfQ is what the user entered)

```
if (latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city1))
        {
            latitudeOfQ = latitudeOfBarrow;
            longitudeOfQ = longitudeOfBarrow;
        }
        else if (latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city2))
        {
            latitudeOfQ = latitudeOfBrisbane;
            longitudeOfQ = longitudeOfBrisbane;
        }
        else if (latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city3))
        {
            latitudeOfQ = latitudeOfDuluth;
            longitudeOfQ = longitudeOfDuluth;
        }
        else if (latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city4))
        {
            latitudeOfQ = latitudeOfLondon;
            longitudeOfQ = longitudeOfLondon;
        }
        else if(latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city5));
        {
            latitudeOfQ = latitudeOfOrlando;
            longitudeOfQ = longitudeOfOrlando;
        }
System.out.print(latitudeOfQ);
System.out.print(longitudeQ);
```

Comment: because this `latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city5)` is always true or `latitudeOfQ` has a default value for orlando (no if worked )

Comment: You should tried that with a loop ;)

Comment: Why don't you use a `switch` statement? Or even better: use a `Map` to store that information then you don't need an `if` at all.

Answer (score 5):

There's an extra `;` causing this:

```
else if(latitudeStringOfQ.equals(city5)); <-- here
    {
        latitudeOfQ = latitudeOfOrlando;
        longitudeOfQ = longitudeOfOrlando;
    }
```

What this actually means is:

- ... else if latitude equals city5, do nothing
- then, in a new block, always use Orlando's coordinates

Comment: Nice catch ! To much of the same code, I didn't even read that far... You should talk about Statement Block that is not restricted to if/switch/loops/methods/class. but can appear anywhere. That is too often skipped during lessons